# Using the Twitter API, how to ensure a tweet comes from a specific source

Tags: api, twitter

If I want to ensure that the tweet comes from a specific service (using Foursquare for example), what is the best way to accomplish this using the API? Is the Users field enough, if I know the ID of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Each Tweet returned by the Twitter API contains a `source` field. The source attribution of a Tweet is set by the name of the application used to create it e.g., Foursquare. So that's the field you should be looking for.

You can see source data in the example API output on this page:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline